# Building Impala depends upon Hive, HBase and Sentry or not?

Tags: hadoop, installation, impala

I have a Hadoop cluster, with one master and 3 slaves. Now, I want to add Apache Impala functionality over this cluster. I've downloaded the tarball from [here](http://impala.apache.org/downloads.html). I want to build Impala, but am not sure what are the prerequisites. There are two different sources:

1. [This](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_prereqs.html#prereqs), from the Docs, which says the requirements are: MySQL (or PostgreSQL), Hive metastore, and Java dependencies (obviously).
2. The `README.md` file inside the `apache-impala` directory created after untarring the tar ball. Quoting it:

   > Impala can be built with pre-built components, downloaded from S3, or
   >   can be built with an in-place toolchain located in the thirdparty
   >   directory (not recommended). The components needed to build Impala are
   >   **Apache Hadoop, Hive, HBase, and Sentry**.

I am confused regarding both the sources. What should I do? A clear set of dependencies for Apache Impala would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you carefully read the [Impala Requirements](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_prereqs.html) you will see that Hadoop support is implied while the Sentry requirement is buried in the [Impala Security](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_security.html#security) link near the bottom of the page.

Under the **Java Dependencies** section it says:

> All Java dependencies are packaged in the impala-dependencies.jar file, which is located at /usr/lib/impala/lib/. These map to everything that is built under fe/target/dependency.

Looking at the corresponding [pom.xml](https://github.com/cloudera/Impala/blob/cdh5-trunk/fe/pom.xml) you will see all the dependencies.  Grepping `artifactId` shows the following:

```
$ grep artifactId fe/pom.xml 
    <artifactId>impala-parent</artifactId>
  <artifactId>impala-frontend</artifactId>
      <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
      <artifactId>impala-data-source-api</artifactId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
          <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
          <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-azure-datalake</artifactId>
          <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
      <artifactId>sentry-core-common</artifactId>
      <artifactId>yarn-extras</artifactId>
      <artifactId>sentry-core-model-db</artifactId>
          <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
      <artifactId>sentry-provider-common</artifactId>
      <artifactId>sentry-provider-db</artifactId>
          <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
      <artifactId>sentry-provider-file</artifactId>
      <artifactId>sentry-provider-cache</artifactId>
          <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
      <artifactId>sentry-policy-common</artifactId>
      <artifactId>sentry-binding-hive</artifactId>
          <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
      <artifactId>sentry-policy-engine</artifactId>
      <artifactId>sentry-service-api</artifactId>
          <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
      <artifactId>parquet-hadoop-bundle</artifactId>
      <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
           <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
      <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
           <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
      <artifactId>hbase-protocol</artifactId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <artifactId>java-cup</artifactId>
      <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
      <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
          <artifactId>hive-llap-server</artifactId>
          <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
      <artifactId>hive-serde</artifactId>
```

So the README.md is correct in stating you need Hadoop, Hive, HBase, and Sentry to build Impala.